# MQ - Peaking Queues in .NET

Tags: msmq

I am relatively new to MS-MQ Development and I was wondering if any of you guru's out there know an answer to the following:

In the concept of queues, there is something called "peaking", whereby; you can look at the message on the queue BUT NOT take it off the queue. This is different to performing a GET call.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not much different than recieving a message from a queue.

```cs
var queue = new MessageQueue([path to queue]);

var msg = queue.Peek();
```

It is also possible to iterate over the messages in the queue by using

```cs
var msg = queue.Peek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), PeekAction.Next);
```

and you can also peek by different Id's

- PeekByCorrelationId
- PeekByLookupId
- PeekById

Check out the examples in the documentation on MSDN for each of these methods as they can get you started quite easily.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/829zyck7.aspx